# why does my view embedded in UIScrollView scroll only a little?

Tags: ios, swift, uiscrollview, storyboard

In my `UIViewController` I put a `UIScrollView` and attached constraints:

[image]

Then I added a view to this scroll view with following constraints:

[image]

and positioned it like this:

[image]

[image]

so as you can see it is quite long. When I run the app I can scroll it just for couple pixels instead of completely to the top of the screen. I want to make it possible to scroll it to the top so that it can cover everything what's under it. So what am I doing wrong here?

========= EDIT

for clarification - I want to achieve an effect that when user opens this screen, 10% of the screen is covered by the view. User can slide up this view and then it covers 90% of the view. And he can slide it down back to the 10%. Can you help me with adjusting constraints so that it looks good on every screen size?

Comment: SO your have you taken any content view and then adding the items to the content view or directly assigning subViews to scrollView ?

Comment: @Janmenjaya basically I want to achieve an effect that when user opens this screen - he sees only part of the view from the bottom and he can swipe it up, so that it covers 90% of the screen. I set up some constraints, but then the lower part of the view is not visible on iphone 4s... how can I set it up so that it looks good on every screen size?

Comment: Does it mean like. Your ScrollView will be from lets say y position 64, but actually to the view it would be shown as 450 something like that, so that it feels like the scrollView starts from 450 but if user swipes up then it will come to original position i.e 64??

Comment: @Janmenjaya so basically I want this: when user opens the panel he sees this: http://imgur.com/aqkFugX and he can scroll the white area to the top until he sees this: http://imgur.com/MZ8RFLs ... can you help me with that?

Comment: See my answer I tried to describe as my best, let me know if it works for you, though I tested it in my demo project

Answer (score 0):

Take a `UIView` inside the `UIScrollView`.

Set the constraint for scroll view as leading, trailing, top, bottom.

Select UIViewController in the story board and click size inspector then choose `freeform` then set the view height as bigger.

Then set constraint of `UIView` is leading , trailing , top , bottom as 0, so that the UIView will be same as ScrollView region. Now set height constraint something bigger so that you can design image view, label 1 and label 2. Then set constraint like the image view : top to UIView, leading , trailing and height. 
For label 1: leading, trailing , vertical to UIImageView, height.
For label 2: leading, trailing , vertical to label 1, height and bottom to UIView (Important as based on this content view will be set).

[image: ScrollView Constraints]

[image: ContentView Constraints]

[image: ImageView Constraint]

[image: Label 1 or top label constraint]

[image: Bottom label constraint]

After setting constraint You can select UIViewControl from story board and set the SizeInspector as fixed as it was before.

It will show the screen as you need (Image view, below label 1 and on scrolling label 2)
I have  tested it in my demo project.

Hope it helps

Comment: hm, do you bother uploading somewhere the demo project so I could see how it works in real life?